# How can I show that the function $f(x)= 2x^5 +3x^4 +2x +16$ takes the value zero exactly once?

Tags: analysis

Apparently I am supposed to use the mean value theorem (this is an analysis question) but I can't see how this could help? All I know about the function is that it is greater than zero for all x>0 and will tend to infinity as x tends to infinity.

Answer (score 1):

the function is not one to one in $(-\infty, \infty).$

since the degree of the polynomial is odd, we know that the range of $f$ is $(-\infty, \infty).$ the derivatives of $f$ are 
$$f'(x) = 10x^4 + 12x^3 + 2, f''(x) = 40x^3 + 36x^2 $$

one can verify that $f'(-1) = 0 = f'(-0.78)$ and that $f'(x) < 0 \text{ for } -1 < x < -0.78$ furthermore that $f(-0.78) = -1.027 < f(x) < f(-1) = -1$ for $-1 < x < -0.78.$  therefore t $f(x) = k$ has three solutions for $f(-1) < k < f(-0.78).$

Comment: f'(-1) =0, so that f'(x) is sometimes equal to zero...

Comment: @user214713, let me check.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

You can easily show that the derivative is larger than zero for all $x<-1$, and $f(x)$ is therefore monotonic in that range. Since $f(-2) < 0$ and $f(-1) > 0$, $f(x)$ crosses zero only once when $x<-1$.

Now we must check the range $-1<x<0$. In this region it is clear that $f(x)>0$.

Q.E.D

Comment: I don't see how it is 'clear' that f(x)>0 for -1<x<0 or that f(x) crosses zero only once for x<-1.

Comment: @user214713 - That's why it's only a hint :) Check what the minimal value $f(x)$ can get in that range, since $|x|<1$.

Comment: aah I see, thanks :)

Comment: @user214713 - If a answer helps you, you are welcome to accept / and or upvote.